# how to rename currently displayed document in web browser control on user form?

Tags: excel, vba, webbrowser-control, userform

I am busy with a userform, to enable the user the view a pdf, make some selections and then rename the pdf. The pdf is displayed in a web browser control.

The display part, works fine, using this code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
Dim fname As String
fname = Me.ListBox1.Value
Dim smURL As String
smURL = "\My Pictures\ControlCenter4\Scan\"
Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate2 smURL & Me.ListBox1.Value

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until Me.WebBrowser1.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE


End
```

this is a later part of the code, used to compile the string. This is where the error occurs`

```
Private Sub CommandButton54_Click()
Dim val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6 As String
val1 = Me.ListBox1.Value
val2 = "\AndreG1\My Pictures\ControlCenter4\Scan\"
val3 = val2 + val1


val4 = Me.TextBox11.Value
val5 = val2 + val4
Unload Me

Name val3 As val5 ''This is where I get the error

MsgBox "File Has Been Re Named", vbOKOnly


With Controls.Add("Forms.WebBrowser.1")
    .Name = "WebBrowser1"

    .Height = 22
    .Left = 6
    .Top = 12
    .Width = 72
    .Visible = True
  End With




Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate2 val5

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until Me.WebBrowser1.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Me.WebBrowser1.Visible = True`
```

I keep getting error 75. Path/File access error.

I suspect that it has to do with the web browser control locking the file?
I have tried:
unload the userform and then change name,
remove the web browser control with me.controls
navigate2 about:blank

I am lost.

Please help

Comment: If you want to assign the value of `val5` to `val3`, try this: `val3 = val5`. `Name vals As val5` is not a valid VBA statement. Also, your declaration of `val` variables (`Dim val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6 As String`) means that only `vals6` is of type **String**. Rest of them are of type **Variant**. In VBA, you have to declare each variable type (i.e. `Dim val1 As String, val2 As String...`)

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks like you are trying to rename your file with: `Name val3 As val5`. In VBA: if you want to rename a file, try using `FileSystemObject`. Also, what type of variable is `Name`?. **Tip**: try not using reserved words as your variable names

Comment: Actually this `val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6` is the worst variable naming I could imagine. Either use an array: `Dim MyArray(1 To 6)` or give your variable meaningful names. Also if you try to concatenate strings `val3 = val2 + val1` you must use `&` instead of `+` because with `+` vba tries to calculate and sum up `val2 + val1` espeacially because they are of type `Variant` (see Zac's first comment).